# In go, how to create a constructor for a type without any arguments

Tags: go

Given this type

```
type Response map[string]interface{}
```

I created a method NewResponse which fills in the default values:

```
 func NewResponse() Response {
    resp := Response{"status": 200, "msg": "Added jobs to queue"}

    resp_metadata := make(map[string]string)
    resp_metadata["base"] = "api/v1"
    resp_metadata["self"] = "/crawler/jobs/add"
    resp["metadata"] = resp_metadata
    return resp
}
```

which i call like `NewResponse()` but I would like to do `Response.New()` instead, so the method signature should be like this

```
func (Response) New() Response {
```

but then I always get the error `not enough arguments in call to Response.New`.

So, how could this be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is definitely not idiomatic Go, you *could* do something [like this](http://play.golang.org/p/ICQZWqrJ9d):

```
type Response map[string]interface{}

func (r *Response) New() {
  *r = make(map[string]interface{})
  (*r)["hello"] = "World"
  (*r)["high"] = 5
}

func main() {
  var r Response
  r.New()
  for k, v := range r {
    fmt.Printf("%s = %v\n", k, v)
  }
}
```

But really, there's nothing wrong with `func NewResponse() Response`.

Comment: Thank you. Kept the initial version but still got how it could be done.

Answer (score 3):

When you write Go programs, use idiomatic Go. Then, other people will be able to read your programs. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Response map[string]interface{}

func NewResponse() Response {
    metadata := map[string]string{
        "base": "api/v1",
        "self": "/crawler/jobs/add",
    }
    r := Response{
        "status":   200,
        "msg":      "Added jobs to queue",
        "metadata": metadata,
    }
    return r
}

func main() {
    resp := NewResponse()
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

Output:

```
map[status:200 msg:Added jobs to queue metadata:map[base:api/v1 self:/crawler/jobs/add]]
```

Comment: Thank you :) I did keep the initial (NewResponse) version but marked PuerkitoBio's response as the answer since it did answer the "how to" question. But now I updated my code to your version. Btw I actually use this to automatically marshall into json like this: func (r Response) String() (s string) {
 b, err := json.Marshal(r)
 if err != nil {
  s = ""
  return
 }
 s = string(b)
 return
} It might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. Go doesn't have constructors. To create an "empty" object is to create a [zero value](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of the type of the object.

What you're trying to do is a Response method named New to be called on an existing Response object that would return a (different) Response object.

`resp := Response{}` or `resp := make(Response)` is fine if you need to create an empty Response.